# Dplyr select() - need numeric data issue

Tags: r, select, dplyr, numeric

I ran into an interesting problem when computing mean/median of a subset of a column in a data frame given a condition.

At this point, I don't need advice, but thought this problem would be interesting to share:

```
testFile <- data.frame(
    ID = 1:10, Value = rnorm(10), 
    Condition = sample(c("Yes", "No"), 10, replace = T)
)
median1 <- median(testFile[testFile$Condition == "Yes", ]$Value)
median2 <- testFile %>% 
    filter(Condition == "Yes") %>% 
    select(Value) %>% 
    median
```

> Error in median.default(.) : need numeric data

However, the following code is working:

```
max2 <- testFile %>% 
    filter(Condition == "Yes") %>% 
    select(Value) %>% 
    max  

values <- testFile %>% 
    filter(Condition == "Yes") %>% 
    select(Value)

class(values[2,1])
```

> [1] "numeric"

Answer (score 3):

Solution from the dplyr result using unlist:

```
median3 <- testFile %>% filter(Condition == "Yes") %>% select(Value) %>% unlist %>% median
```

Non-dplyr solution, as was already mentioined in the OP:

```
> median1 <- median(testFile[testFile$Condition == "Yes", ]$Value) # Working
```

Comment: If `testFile %>% filter(Condition == "Yes") %>% select(Value) %>%  class` gives `data.frame`, why do further evaluations, e.g. `median` necessitate `unlist`?

Comment: @M.Teich The reason is that these functions do not work on dataframes. Think about it, median/mean are mathematically defined on a vector of numbers. R help for median input states: _an object for which a method has been defined, or a numeric vector_.

Data.frame is internally implemented a list of equal-length vectors. Thus, the median cannot be used for that. `unlist` creates a vector out of data.frame values. Notice also that while you cannot calculate `median(testFile)`,  `median(testFile[, 1])` works, for the same reasons - in the second case you are working with vector of 1st column

Comment: Interesting fact is that median/mean work on matrices in R. But then, if you look under the hood, a matrix is implemented as a vector that is distributed in columns/rows, therefore it does not violate the input format for hte mean/median functions